# awk problems: problems summing non-integers?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

So i'm writing a bash script that has to figure out how much CPU is being used in total according to the command "ps u". I'm trying to use awk like so:

```
TOTAL_CPU=$(ps u | awk '{sum = sum + $3}; END {print sum}')
```

Typical output from the command "ps u" has 11 columns, the 3rd being CPU usage.

The problem is, this isn't working like it should. When the CPU value has decimals, I get an error like this:

```
syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".x")
```

Where x is the "remaining" decimals after the sum. For example if the values are "1.4" and "8.7", the sum is "10.1", so the error will say:

```
syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".1")
```

How can I do what I need? It's ok if the decimal gets truncated, I don't need lots of precision.

EDIT: the post editor changed what I had originally written

EDIT2: Problem solved! It wasn't awk's fault at all; it turns out that this line of code was hiding somewhere else:

```
declare -i TOTAL_CPU
```

So bash was trying to assign a value like "3.4" to a variable that was expected to contain integer values only. I'm putting this here in case someone finds this post via google later!

Comment: This works for me in bash, both on a command line and in a script.  Perhaps you could post your full script.  Might be something other than this command that's at fault.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `ps` command in the manpage on your system. You can reformat the `ps` output to get what you want. For example, you can just print out the CPU amount and forget the rest of the output:

```
sum=$(ps -udavid -o %cpu | tail -n +2 | paste  -sd+ - | bc)
```

- `ps -udavid`: Processes owned by *david*
- `ps -udavid -o %cpu`: Processes owned by david. Just showing the CPU
- `tail -n +2`: Remove the header line (all lines 2 to the end)
- `paste -sd+ -` The `-s` means to combine all lines together in a single line. The `d+` means put a `+` sign after each *line*. The final `-` means use STDIN.
- `bc` calculate the lines. Since all numbers are separated by `+` signs, it will add all the CPU amounts together.

Comment: I like the aesthetic of this technique. I put the two of these samples in a quick Perl benchmark (i.e. Benchmark::cmpthese). For what it's worth, the pipeline technique comes out around 13% faster.

Answer (score 1):

Change it from:

```
TOTAL_CPU=ps u | awk '{sum = sum + $3}; END {print sum}'
```

To:

```
TOTAL_CPU=$(ps u | awk '{sum = sum + $3}; END {print sum}')
```

It's not an `awk` issue, but rather your bash syntax.

The `$(...)` notation is called [Command Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html). Basically, it spawns a new subshell from your current shell to execute whatever command is enclosed by it, and then returns the output to the new subshell's `stdout`.

Comment: The stack overflow editor changed it. I'm using the "``" operator instead of $() which does the same thing.

Comment: @DemianDawid, then I'm not sure what the issue might be, I just ran `TOTAL_CPU=$(ps u | awk '{sum = sum + $3}; END {print sum}')` exactly as described, and when I `echo $TOTAL_CPU` I get `7.3` on my stdout

Comment: well, that's weird. I also tested it on a terminal and it works, but inside the script it doesn't. It's been driving me crazy for a while now...

Comment: @DemianDawid post your full script? I don't think it's an awk issue. Alternatively, run your script with `bash -x script_name` for debug mode

Comment: Instead of `{sum = sum + $3};` you should use `{sum = sum + $3};;;;;;;;;;;;;;` since spurious semi-colons must be desirable ;-).

Comment: @EdMorton: doh, forgot to clean up OP's syntax when I copy and pasted his question to use as part of my answer =/